# Slope of a straight line

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

Why is this so that a higher value of slope indicates a steeper incline? I can't take it into my head. What could be the reason behind that? I know that it is a fact because I've also noticed it but don't know the reason which could assist my understanding of this concept.

Comment: It has to go one way or the other for the idea to be worth talking about. In a sense it is a matter of convention whether a steeper incline has a higher value for slope, or a lower one (it can be done consistently the other way about). Much better to get used to the way it is than to worry. Steeper = higher is a way of remembering, and is also pretty much why it is the way it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think about why $$\text{slope}=\frac{\text{rise}}{\text{run}}=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x},$$ where the $\Delta$ means "change in". The more the $y$ changes over an interval of a fixed length (so $\Delta x$ is fixed), the slope will get larger. Conversely, if the slope gets larger and $\Delta x$ is fixed, then $\Delta y$ must get larger.

Answer (score 6):

Well we could take these two lines as an example.

a) $y=x+1$

b) $y= 10x+1$

In line a, we find that the slope is x which is equal to $\dfrac 11$ which means rise 1, run 1.

In line b, we find that the slope is $10x$ which is equal to $\dfrac {10}1$ which means rise 10, run 1.

Notice the difference in the rise of both lines even though the y-intercept's are the same.